# How do I climb down from the hideout in Firewatch?

Tags: firewatch

I got stuck in the hideout and couldn't find my own way out, except for some glitches in map wall mesh, very much like in this video:

But that sounds very far from the proper way to get down.  I'm pretty sure there should be a stone with a coil of rope tied to it that I could use, but there isn't. Please, explain how it should be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the hideout, there is a table with a bunch of junk on it, including a placard of some description. If you pick up and move the placard, you will discover a set of [pitons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piton) which are required to progress any further.

Like the rope and the flashlight, the pitons are an unlimited use item that let you create a place to hang some rope when there isn't a place to tie some rope otherwise. The only requirement is that you have some place to drive the piton into first.

At 1:27 in the video you linked, the player looks back at the hideout and zooms in. You can clearly see a highlighted crack in the rock:

[image: Rock with piton crack]

That is where you were supposed to drive a piton into, creating a place to hang a rope and allowing you to rappel down to the path below.